# Virtual Host not parsing PHP

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

Alright, I have spent hours searching through very similar questions but I still don't seem to have found the answer:

I have set up a virtual host with the following in my `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.dev
    ServerAlias test.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Users/OrangeSoda/OneDrive/Projects/Test/Website"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/test.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/test.dev-access_log" common

    <Directory "/Users/OrangeSoda/OneDrive/Projects/Test/Website">
         Options all
         AllowOverride all
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

In my `http.conf` I have `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` as well as `LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so` uncommented.

When I go to test.dev/index.php which just has `<?php echo "PHP TEST"; ?>`, I see the contents of the file output as a string.

It seems as though PHP is not enabled and is therefore not being recognized.

If i go to localhost, I do see the "It Works!" page, so I know php is working, just for some reason not on my virtual host.

Someone suggested to put `php_admin_flag engine on` but that just makes the whole page crash.

Does anybody understand why php is not enabled here?

Comment: so where's the php module loaded in apache? maybe it's enabled on a per-directory or per-vhost basis only.

Comment: What do you get when you use `php -v` in the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that while php was enabled, for some reason the default setting in `httpd.conf` was not to read .php files as .php.

Although I am not really sure why that would not be the default setting, I added the following to my `httpd.conf` and now it works just fine:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if port 80 is opened? It might help more if you include detailed log.

Comment: I know the port is opened because I can view html pages on my virtual host, javascript works as well, it is just php which is not being rendered

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but you need to actually load php onto the virtual host. On the `<Directory>` entry, add these lines :

```
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
    php_admin_flag engine on
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_admin_flag engine on
</IfModule>
```

I got the solution from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/php-not-working-on-one-vhost-but-works-on-all-others-851093/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mod-php may not be installed. What OS are you on?

On Ubuntu/debian:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

on redhat:

```
sudo yum install php
```